# How to minimize the integral of the functional of a function, with respect to that function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, maxima-minima

I need to obtain the function $f(x)$ for which the following integral has  its minimum value:

$I=\int F(f(x))dx= \int [A (B^2-f(x)^2)^2-Cf(x)f''(x)]dx$

One special solution is $f(x)=constant=\pm B$, but I need the general solution such that $f(x) \ne constant$. Then the systematic approach is to minimize '$I$' with respect to $f(x)$. I started with $\dfrac{dI}{df(x)}=0 $.

Then I differentiate both side with respect to $x$ so that I get rid of the integral and end up with $\dfrac{dF(f(x))}{df(x)}=0 $

This step gives me:  $2A(B^2-f(x)^2).[-2f(x)] -C\dfrac{d}{df(x)}f(x)f''(x)=0$

At this point how to carry out the second part? Shall I consider the $f''(x)$ be constant with respect to $f(x)$? Doing so would give a differential equation to solve for $f(x)$. But I am not sure whether this is the right way or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having $f$ not being constant is different from $f''$ not being zero everywhere; $f(x) = x$ is not constant, yet has second derivative zero.

Comment: This is a standard calculus of variation problem. The solution is given by a 2nd order diff equation in $f$ which looks to be solvable. You need to specify if the end points are fixed or not.

Comment: The end points are not fixed. I did not get your point, how should I obtain the 2nd order diff. equation in $f$? As you see, if I take $f''(x)$ be constant with respect to $f(x)$, I get the term $C\dfrac{d}{df(x)}f(x)f''(x)=Cf''(x)$. Thereby I would get a 2nd order diff. equation. However I don't get any logic for taking  $f''(x)$ to be constant with respect to $f(x)$. Could you please give a little more detail? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply 'spot' the function you need. The reason I go this route is because it's not clear (to me at least) what it means to differentiate the expression with respect to a function, so doing so won't help.

Take $f(x) := B$; then:
$$ A(B^2 - f(x)^2)^2 - Cf(x)f''(x) = A \cdot 0 - C \cdot B \cdot 0 = 0,$$

i.e. your integral is zero. Note though that to properly minimise the function, you need to specify some boundaries.

Comment: The solution you presented is in fact the only known special case (not boundary). The integral equation is derived from an assumption that $f(x)$ is not uniform throughout the space, therefore $f''(x)$ is non-zero. Under that condition the integral must be minimized for acceptable $f(x)$. Definitely final solution would be a function of the constants as well as $f''(x)$, something like $f(x)=B.g(A,C,f''(x))$. 

Please look in my first description, if take $f''(x)$ be constant with respect to $f(x)$ I will get a differential equation to solve for f(x). I was wondering am I on the right track?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the differentiation either, that is why I am asking for help.

Known facts are-

a) $f(x)=B$ is an special solution for $f(x)$. This is the most ideal case.


b) In practice we have deviation from ideal situation and therefore $f''(x)$ is not zero.


c) $f(x)$ can have any other (possibly infinite number of) solutions, provided that the value of the integral is minimum for a given $f(x)$

Comment: @Alam If you wished to find a non-constant $f$, then please edit your original question appropriately.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Hope this is much clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The Euler Lagrange equation for $f$ to be an extremum of the integral $\int^b_a F(x,f,f',f'') dx$ is

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial f}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial f'}+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{\partial F}{\partial f''}$.

For the given $F$ this gives $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}[A(B^2-f^2)^2]-Cf''-C\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f$. Multiply this through by $f'$ and integrate to get

$[A(B^2-f^2)^2]+D=C f'^{\,2}$ where $D$ is a constant to be determined.
It looks possible, but ugly, to integrate this again, so getting something neat and tidy like $f(x)=....$ is probably not on.
If $f$ is fixed at $x=a$ and $x=b$ then these are the bc's. If $f$ is not fixed then calculus of variation provides natural boundary conditions. I believe these are $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$ but check.

In the original integral the term $f f''$ can be integrated by parts to give $f'^2$. This is why we end up with only a second order equation and not a third order.